# Enable OAuth in PHP - Azure App Service

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service

Good evening,

We are working with some developers in the creation of one of our first apps, using Microsoft Azure Cloud hosting for the platform.

We are trying to get the bitly API to work from our server however we have been informed by our devs that they are unable to utilise this, with a suspect cause being that the OAuth module isn't listed within the info.php of the Azure App service with the files uploaded.

What we are looking for is to enable the OAuth capabilities for the PHP web app, however we aren't sure how to reconfigure the environment with no root access to the base server (as a result of the Azure App service).  Normally we would utilise the PECL or YUM package for OAuth and then reconfigure it for php to be able to access it, however obviously this time we can't.

Wanted OAuth Configuration:
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMoZA.png)

Can anyone help us enable the OAuth for this application?

Thanks!

Comment: any update yet?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps support custom PHP extensions in the default PHP runtime. Please try the following steps to achieve your requirement.

1. Download the DLL file of OAuth extension from https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth, select the nts & x86 version.
2. Add a `ext` directory to your root directory. Copy the dll file into this directory.
3. Create an ini file in the root directory called `extensions.ini`
4. Add configuration settings to the `extensions.ini` file using the same syntax you would use in a `php.ini` file. E.G.

   `extension = d:\home\site\wwwroot\ext\php_oauth.dll`
5. Add an App Setting to your Web App on Azure protal with the key `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` and value `d:\home\site\ini`
6. Deploy your application to Azure Web app, and restart the Azure Web Apps service.

Leverage `phpinfo()` you can see the extension configured correct,
[image]
You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime for more info.